# Where should I ask a question related to English document reviews?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where should I ask a question related to English document reviews?

---

Something like [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but refactoring English documents instead of refactoring the code. So that I could learn from refactoring my sentences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no site for reviewing English documents.

You could propose a site for document reviews on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com).

Apart from that, it seems your purpose is to improve your command of English grammar. You might have use for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). Note, however, that according to their Help Center, proofreading is explicitly **off**-topic:

(From the "Do not ask"):

> Proofreading (for example, "Are there any mistakes?" or "Is this correct?"), unless a source of concern is clearly specified

Unfortunately (as Dan Bron points out in their [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291724/where-should-i-ask-a-question-related-to-english-document-reviews#comment947357_291725)), the same applies to our other site about English, [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com). They have the exact same rule in their Help Center.

As ColleenV points out in their [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291724/where-should-i-ask-a-question-related-to-english-document-reviews#comment947357_291725), ELL does have a post on their per-site meta dealing with this. They are asked more often if people would proofread for them, so they have [this Meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/alternative-websites-for-proofreading) for people who need proofreaders.

Comment: Thanks , But is there a site on `Stackexchange.com` to ask about sites or applications to do that ?

Comment: Proof-reading is off-topic on ELL, but we do have a discussion on our meta site that lists some [alternative sites for proof-reading](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/263/) that might help. @AnynameDonotcare

Comment: We do have a site where you can ask for software; [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). However, that site is **very** restricive on what questions are allowed. They must prevent spam, so to ask a question there, you must have very clear requirements. To be honest, I don't think there is software to review entire documents. NLP (natural language processing) is surprisingly difficult for computers.

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare SE is not a panacea... It is not all things for all people. I doubt this sort of thing would ever be on topic as there are thousands of sites out there already and it's largely a matter of opinion. Also, many sites require payment for this as they are acting as an editor. You're looking for someone to do for free what they'd normally be paid for.

Comment: Please note that proof-reading is also explicitly off-topic on ELL's sister site, EL&U.se (just in case anyone sees "don't ask on ELL" and thinks "ok, I'll ask on ELU instead"). As the answer says, as of this writing, there is no such site on the network.

Comment: @DanBron, ColleenV: thank you both! I have edited this information into the answer.

Comment: Proofreading and critiques are also off-topic on Writers.